# Most useful javascript design patterns for a single page application that updates with AJAX?

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, single-page-application

For a beginner (and hobbyist) who is well self-schooled in HTML and CSS and is moderately familiar with JavaScript which design patterns should he learn and apply? My task is to create a single page application without using any libraries or frameworks. It would be a simple site that updates content only in sections of the page as they are clicked. Although it would be a one page web the address bar as well as a menu would mimick a multi-page website. It will not be built as a mobile phone app but may be accessible via one as all web sites are. The goal is use this as learning experience while building an online portfolio. It would likely be hosted at Github Pages which permits AJAX updates. Please advise.

Comment: step 1: please see 
[how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), 
and take the 
[tour of the site](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: Is it worth it? I mean, you will end up writing your own framework for data-binding, rendering, ajax, etc. Why not use an already-stable framework?

Comment: @JaromandaX thanks for the advice. My apologies if this question does not fit the standards set by this amazing site. But I really don't know where else to turn for such information or how to ask it better. I shall look into the links you provided.

Comment: @Leo my goal is to learn JavaScript the right way. Hence why I won't even bother to use jQuery. Once I learn it then I shall turn to using libraries and frameworks which should be very efficient. Thanks for the response.

Comment: You simply cannot do this in a reasonable and common-sense fashion. Frameworks for making SPA-s are there because there exists a need for them, not because people want to use fancy frameworks. There is SOOOO much you need to do in order to get something simple running properly its insane without using such frameworks. It is not how you learn javascript, that is for sure. Start much smaller, make one-page non-application content, small games for kids of like grade-1, simple additions, animations, dom manipulations, etc. Then progress, you cannot start with building a space-shuttle

Comment: @Dellirium are you suggesting that I should just use Jekyll which is available on GitHub Pages and just learn the JavaScript as I need it?

Comment: @JulesManson fair enough Dellirium makes a good point though. Starting small, then add bits and pieces as you go. Then as you advance and attempt to refactor your code you will find yourself asking more specific questions about design patterns

Comment: @Leo Yes that would be my learning path. I guess I jumped the gun a little. But I am a very fast learner hence why I am motivated to learn advanced techniques.

Answer (score 0):

There is an eBook from 2016 called "Build Your Own AngularJS". It will be terribly outdated, but for educational purposes it could be valuable for someone wanting to learn how to handle complexity. It's free to download now, so you could give it a try: https://teropa.info/build-your-own-angular